# How edit the error page to show custom text instead of "There has been an error processing your request"

Tags: magento-1.9, error, custom

I would like to change the look of error page and put different text. What is the path to related file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path of a default error page (page with report) is `errors/default/report.phtml`. Other error pages can be found in `errors/default/`.

Comment: i was start thinking you only do only editing part :P

Comment: @QaisarSatti Just because I like to put everything in order ;)

Comment: you are twinkling like a star today :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own errors skin by creating new folder inside errors folder at magento's root directory. Copy all of the files from default to new folder and customize them. Now set your folder as skin by creating new file local.xml inside errors folder or modify design.xml and place following content in this file

```
<config>
<skin>newfoldername</skin>
</config>
```

For more you can see local.xml.sample placed in errors folder.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error page file on follwing directory and you can edit message.

> errors/default/report.phtml

Comment: kindly don't add the duplicate or identical answer.